# Where is scrollbar in listView?

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollbar

In the .xml file, a layout written shows as follow, pls check up,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1a"
    android:background="@color/dodgerblue"
    android:entries="@array/Planets"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/Medium_Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/green" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Build gets through, But when run in emulator, there is no scrollbar in the listview, what's matter?

[image]

```
<string-array name="Planets">  
    <item>Mercury</item>  
    <item>Venus</item>  
    <item>Earth</item>  
    <item>Mars</item>  
    <item>Jupiter</item>  
    <item>Saturn</item>  
    <item>Uranus</item>  
    <item>Neptune</item>  
    <item>Pluto</item>                 
    <item>Moon</item>
    <item>Satellite</item>

</string-array>
```

this is array data.
and can add more data bellow.

Comment: Does u have that much contains to scroll the listview?

Comment: Your listview will only scroll when it has enough items that they will go out of screen

Comment: Only one listview includes 8-9items. I can't see the rest item in the box. the box can show 5items.

Comment: Some doc suggests to add the statement: android:fadeScrollbars="false", but I can't find the fadescrollbar properties in the listview graphic layout.

Comment: Look at the picture, I wish to see scrollbar at right, but no one now.

Comment: @learner1 scrollbar is only visible while scrolling. It seems that your `listview` is not being added with enough items. Please post the code where you are adding the items to the listview

Comment: @Rohan, there they are. I add code above. the entry is planets.     android:entries="@array/Planets"

Comment: please post your complete layout xml. There might be some problem there or it should have shown all the values.

Comment: the rest may have nothing to do with it. It's rather trouble for us to use and access to this forum. Would you pls show us what matter it may be? what will it be caused?

Comment: well, I put down more codes of the layout. nearly whole except two button layout.

Comment: I tried it in my sample project and it worked completely fine. I still think that you did something wrong in your code.

Comment: try making a simple xml with just the listview and then you will see that it is scrolling and then try add other `textviews` one by one.

Comment: I try a new activity with only one listview, but still fail to show the scrollbar.

Comment: I find when I press down the left key and move up or down, the scrollbar display, when release it will disappear soon.