# No media use in program, but logcat shows many wrong about it. what's matter? and what do they mean?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-logcat

In the logcat, there are these wrong messages, what does that mean?

```
11-11 13:44:34.253: E/cutils-trace(3996): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-11 13:44:51.153: E/cutils-trace(4012): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-11 15:58:40.922: E/InputDispatcher(288): channel '41aba520 com.example.andrappexp1/com.example.andrappexp1.SecondActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-11 15:59:38.913: E/SoundPool(288): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-11 15:59:38.942: E/SoundPool(288): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-11 15:59:38.962: E/SoundPool(288): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-11 15:59:38.962: E/SoundPool(288): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-11 16:00:04.642: E/SoundPool(288): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-11 16:00:04.672: E/SoundPool(288): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-11 16:00:04.703: E/SoundPool(288): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-11 16:10:26.484: E/SoundPool(288): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-11 19:13:47.702: E/SoundPool(288): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-11 19:13:47.732: E/SoundPool(288): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
```

There is no any context of media in my program, why occur such information?

Comment: And what makes you think that these messages relate to your App?

Comment: My app is com.example.andrappexp1.SecondActivity .so I think it may be that.

Comment: I have lots of ideas but they're so simple that I can't imagine you don't have them yourself. Maybe the first step in the right direction would be to eliminate the idea that these messages are "wrong" from your thoughts. If Android searches for these files and sees their non-existance as an error, it must be configured to do so. But there's also a possibility that these errors aren't even so relevant -- unfortunately, you're not revealing much information in this regard.

Comment: Thank you. You may be right at config setting. I seem not config this side. I t seems to have nothing to do with running prog.

Answer (score 1):

You are observing Android's raw log output, while you are likely interested in only messages that relate to your application. Eclipse and Android Studio provide mechanisms to filter only those messages that you're interested in, particularly by the application package name.

Unless you're certain that your application is triggering these errors, I wouldn't pay too much attention to it as it may simply be another app on your phone may be responding to an installation event. If you'd like to figure out which application is causing it, look its process id up in the running processes.

Comment: thank you for your comment. to ignor it may be right. Im uncertain whick app trigs it, only am I aware of running an app shown at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471731/where-is-scrollbar-in-listview?noredirect=1#comment30633515_20471731. you can refer to that.